# Separate org-file-apps for export

Tags: org-mode, microsoft-windows

I use org-mode for a lot of things, but two of them are now in conflict. The two use cases are (1) drafting assignments and exporting to LaTeX and (2) tracking my reference library using RefTeX. My default system PDF reader is Acrobat, which is great for reading and annotating PDFs. However, it's not so great when you're exporting from org to LaTeX, because it locks the file, meaning you have to close it to redo the export. Recently I added the following lines to my configuration on Windows to use SumatraPDF instead, because it allows for live updates of the file without closing:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-file-apps
   (quote
    ((auto-mode . emacs)
     ("\\.mm\\'" . default)
     ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default)
     ("\\.pdf\\'" . "C:/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe %s")))))
```

The issue is that when I open PDF links from my reference library, they now (of course) open in SumatraPDF, when I would rather be using Acrobat, the system default. Is there a way to either (a) select a different PDF viewer only for org-mode exports or (b) specify to use the default PDF viewer when opening links from my reference notes file?

Comment: Maybe you could get Emacs Docview mode running just for checking the latex export?

Comment: File local variables for the pdf viewer maybe?